# neural network validation accuracy plateaus but sample accuracy over .90%

Tags: python, tensorflow

Training a neural network model the sample accuracy is over 90% but the validation accuracy is around 60%.

process_dataset file is here

https://github.com/interestingdatahuh/process_dataset72623

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Softmax , LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats


n_train = 70


import scipy.io
data = scipy.io.loadmat( 'process_dataset.mat' )
data = data['data']
y_train0 = data[:,1]  #y labels
x_train0 = data[:,4:51] #x labels


#encode
y_train = y_train0[0:n_train].reshape(-1,)  
y_train = pd.get_dummies(y_train) #Encode ylabel
y_train = np.array( y_train.astype(int) )
y_trainOG = y_train #Get original data to be used later for shuffling

#scale data
x_train = x_train0[0:n_train]
xmean = np.mean(x_train, 0)
std = np.std(x_train,0)


#scale data
xmin = np.min(x_train, 0)
xmax = np.max(x_train, 0)
a1 = (x_train - xmin)
x_train = 2*a1/(xmax - xmin) -1


#encode
y_test = y_train0[n_train:n_train+30].reshape(-1,)  
y_test = pd.get_dummies(y_test) #Encode ylabel
y_test = np.array( y_test.astype(int) )

#scale test data

x_test = x_train0[n_train:n_train+30]
xmin = np.min(x_test, 0)
xmax = np.max(x_test, 0)
xmean = np.mean( x_test, 0)
std = np.std(x_test, 0) 
x_test = 2*(x_test - xmin)/(xmax - xmin) -1



def my_model(x):

    
    x = Dense( 50 )(x)
    x = LeakyReLU()(x)  
   
    x = Dense(25   )(x)
    x = LeakyReLU()(x)
    
    x = Dense( 50  )(x)
    x = LeakyReLU()(x)
    
    #x = Dense( 10  )(x)


    x = Dense(5 , activation='softmax', name='output1')(x)
    
 
    return x


main_input = Input((47,))

out1 = my_model( main_input    )
model = Model( inputs = [main_input    ] , outputs=[out1 ] )  
model.summary()
optim = optimizers.SGD(lr= 0.001, momentum=0 )
loss1 = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy

losses = { "output1":loss1 }
model.compile(optimizer=optim, loss=losses, metrics=['accuracy']  )
history =  model.fit( x_train, [y_train ], epochs=2000, batch_size=5 , shuffle = True, validation_data = (x_test, y_test) )

a1 = model.evaluate(x_train, [y_train ])
acc = history.history['accuracy']

plt.plot(acc)
```

I have tried different scaling (i.e. mean and standard dev, 0 and 1, -1 and 1)
Also tried changing the number of hidden layers and neurons
Also tried changing the activations (relu, tanh)
none of these worked
Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: it looks like your train are samples from 0 to n and the test are samples from n to n+30.  Are you sure this splitting that you do makes both sets representative? You are not shuffling or anything, which would be quite common when splitting data into train and test.  Then you don't seem to be using a validation set or doing any crossvalidation.  Your model is basically overfitting or one of the sets is not a representative sample of the whole set.

Comment: if you are asking if the dataset used in testing and training classes has low frequency, I tried with double the size of training and test in the above and still get the same trend.  I checked and for the case where I have double the size of training and test, I have a minimum of at least 10 examples for each class.

Comment: how many classes do you have?

Comment: I have five classes

Comment: So 5 classes and your testing set has 30 examples. It means only 6 samples of each type for testing. That's a quite small test set.